# Is it possible to create a css container without an additional div inside the parent tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple header in css and html.

I would like the background of the header to expand as the browser window expands, however the content must remain at a fixed size. Like `max-width: 1024px` for example.

Usually, i would do something like this :

```html
<!-- Header with a div container -->
<header>
    <div class="header__container">
        <a href="">Link</a>
        <a href="">Link</a>
        <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
header {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.header__container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

Is it possible to do this in css without using a div `container` inside the `header` tag ?

```html
<!-- Header without a div container -->
<header>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
</header>
```

[image]

Thank you for your support.

Comment: For a plain color, you can use box-shadow `header { max-width:1024px;margin:auto;box-shadow: 1000px 0 gold, -1000px 0 gold;}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
body{
  margin: 0
}
header {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.header__container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 calc((100vw - 1024px)/2);
  
  /* The lines below are just for illustration */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024){
  .header__container{
    padding: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header__container">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
</header>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```css
header{
    background: red;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1024px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1024px) / 2);
}
```

```html
<header>
  Content
</header>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).